# What is the right way to ask the number of your spectacles?

Tags: phrase-request

Here people ask like this what is the power of your eye or what is number of your spectacles is it right way to ask.  What is the way to ask the eyesight. Describe it.

Comment: Yeah you are right.Its my mistake

Comment: @Sina, spectacles isn't old fashioned, it's technical- a term used by people in the profession. Laymen talk about glasses.

Comment: But spectacles gives the same meaning nd so I want to know the right way to ask.

Comment: Here fashion doesn't matter

Comment: I would ask "How good is your eyesight?" but the answer to that doesn't have to be a [visual acuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_acuity) score.

Answer (score 4):

The normal way to ask is

> What is your prescription?

or

> What is your eye prescription?

or

> What is your prescription for glasses?

The main part of the answer is a figure in dioptres- this is the strength of the lens needed to correct your sight for distance. Long-sighted people have a positive number and short sighted people have a negative number. There are additional figures to adjust your sight whilst reading, and for [astigmatism](http://www.allaboutvision.com/conditions/astigmatism.htm).

Another way of describing your vision is your [visual acuity](http://www.allaboutvision.com/eye-test/). Not many people know this term, but most people know that 20/20 vision is very good. What it means is that you can read letters from 20 feet away that most people can read from 20 feet away. A visual acuity of 20/200 means that you are practically blind: you can read letters from 20 feet away that most people can read from 200 feet away.

Comment: Is it always used, or just when u go to buy glasses prescribed for you?

Comment: It's always asked

Comment: @sina I wear so I face this question always.

Comment: @Sina, you can easily check things like that using NGram. Here is an example: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eyesight+score&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Comment: @Sina, try this: https://books.google.com/ngrams then type in **eyesight score**

Comment: It means that the internet connection that you are using is restricting what you can access on the internet.  I don't know why. Try googling NGram.

Comment: I think "eyeglass prescription" is the most common way to refer to it (at least in the US).

Comment: @Sina If you search [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) for `eyesight score,vision score,eyeglass prescription` you'll see eyesight score is very unusual (none of the books Google has indexed have it). I would understand what you meant by it, but 'vision score' or the other phrases JavaLatte has explained would be better. See [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eyesight+score%2Cvision+score%2Ceyeglass+prescription&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: @javalatte I think you are right. Acuity is not a new word it's means same for visionscore.  So I like this to ask

Answer (score 1):

In addition to "What is your eye prescription?", another broadly used question is

> How (good / bad) is your eyesight?

As @ColleenV mentioned in the comment, it would be a little friendlier to use "how good". But it is not wrong to use "how bad" among close friends.

Also, you can ask about the glasses or contact lenses as follows:

> What is the (optical) power (strength) of your glasses (contact lenses)?

You need to note that the noun [*(optical) power*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_power) is used when you refer to "glasses" or "contact lenses".

Comment: I would say "how good is your eyesight" instead of "how bad" just to be a bit friendlier. If they're wearing glasses, it's obvious it's not perfect, but it may not be terrible. Then they can answer "oh, it's not too bad. I'm just a little [nearsighted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nearsighted)." I wear glasses and  honestly couldn't tell you what my exact prescription is without looking it up. If the glasses are really thick, it might be more appropriate to ask "how bad".

Comment: I appreciate you incorporating some of my comments, but I up-voted it before you did, so it looks good to me. I think "strength" is a good addition to the other things mentioned here. You could say something like "Those lenses seem thick - how strong are they?"